# How to make an admin panel to review the entries per field in Django?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-admin

I am working on making an application in which users can submit entries and each submitted entry is reviewed by site admin.

- Each entry has many fields and some fields can be accepted and some fields can be rejected.
- For adding this functionality in admin, I added a custom view to
  admin at '/review' url. Now in this view I want to create the
  functionality to accept or reject a field, so that when the form is
  submitted, I can take further actions based on that.
- Till now i am able to render the modelform.
- Now I want something like checkbox per field to mark a field as accepted or rejected, based on which I can take action in view. One way will be to create a form and then create BooleanField for each field manually.

How to accomplish this in DRY way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, your particular question is about constructing a form with checkboxes for all the model's fields. Here's the way to do it:

```
class ReviewForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, model, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReviewForm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        for field in model._meta.get_fields():
            self.fields[field.name] = forms.BooleanField(label=field.name, initial=True)


def triage_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = ReviewForm(Entry, data=request.POST or None) 
    # do stuff with that form, for example
    accepted_field_names = [key for key, val in form.cleaned_data if val]
```

Comment: Yeah that's the thing, let me try it.

Comment: I want one extra boolean field per field i.e modelform + extra boolean field per field

Comment: Sure, just add something like `self.fields['%s_extra' % field.name] = forms.BooleanField(label='Extra %s % 'field.name, default=False)` to your form constructor.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Small thing, default should be replaced with initial